# Integrating unit vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

If I want to find a function $V(r)$ such that ${\bf F} = -\nabla V$, where ${\bf F} = f(r)\hat{\bf r}$, how do I integrate ${\bf F}$ along the radial direction?

Comment: Did you want to make $\mathbf F$?  You can type `{\mathbf F}`.  Oh wait, you have that at the end.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you @BrianTung

Comment: You need to be more specific, what do you mean my "integrate"? a line integral? which path? a volume integral? a surface integral?

Comment: @caverac I meant integrate along the radial direction

Answer (score 0):

Let for $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^d$ let $r=|\vec{x}|$. Note that if $g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then the gradient of the function $V(\vec{x})= g(|\vec{x}|)$ is given by 
$$
\displaystyle \nabla V = \frac{\vec{r}}{r}g'.
$$
Thus to solve your problem we need to find $g$ such that
$$
-\frac{\vec{r}}{r}g'(r)=f(r)\vec{r},
$$
which leads to
$$
g(r)=-\int_0^r f(t)\,t\,dt + C.
$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. But shouldn't the rhs in the second equation read $\f(r)\hat{\bf r}$? And f is not explicitly a function of t so it cannot be integrated that way.

Comment: In my notation $\hat{\bf r}=\vec{r}$. As far as I understood, in your problem ${\bf F}$ is radial so there exists a  function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that ${\bf F}=f(r)\vec{r},$ where $|\vec{r}|=r$ . If so, then $f$ can be integrated as above. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are not. I understand now that we clarified the notation. Though $\nabla r = \hat{\bf r}$, whereas you have $\nabla r = \frac{ \vec{r}}{r}$ in the first equation

Comment: For $\vec{r}=(r_1,\dots, r_d)$ we have $\partial_i r= \partial_i (|\vec{r}|)=\partial_i (\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d} r_k^2)=\frac{r_i}{\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d} r_k^2} $, so $\nabla r=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$.

Comment: But you defined $\vec{r}$ to be the unit vector?